# Consumir um JSON com Javascript!

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Eu tenho um JSON com os seguintes dados de alguns produtos:

- Nome
- Foto
- Preço

E tenho alguns cards no HTML que gostaria que eles se apresentassem ali; Como eu poderia consumir esse JSON para mostrar ele dentro destes cards.

*OBS: Os cards são apenas espaços para entrar a imagem, preço e o nome do produto.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um ID em cada um dos elementos HTML que vai receber as informações, por exemplo usando um card do Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="card shadow" style="width: 18rem;">
    <img id="avatar" class="card-img-top" src="#" alt="Image">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h5 id="first_name" class="card-title"></h5>
        <p id="last_name" class="card-text"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Use o `fetch` do JavaScript passando a URL da sua API, neste exemplo para colocar os dados e a imagem de um usuário no card anterior fazemos:

```
const url = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2'; // Troque pela URL da sua API

function readJson() {
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error("Erro HTTP: " + response.status);
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(json => {
            this.response = json;
            document.getElementById('avatar').src = response.data.avatar;
            document.getElementById('first_name').innerHTML = response.data.first_name;
            document.getElementById('last_name').innerHTML = response.data.last_name;
        })
        .catch(function () {
            this.dataError = true;
        })
}

readJson();
```

Segue o [link](https://codepen.io/tkrempser/pen/OGJJWo) deste exemplo em funcionamento.

Comment: Esse vai funcionar, porém eu tenho um JSON local como eu poderia encontrar ele por meio da const url = '../assets/products.json' seria desta forma?

Comment: Você deve instalar um servidor web localmente e usar localhost com sua URL.

Comment: Consegui hospedar ela em uma página https://thaleshenrique38.000webhostapp.com/products.json porém mesmo colocando o URL e os ID's iguais os da aplicação acaba não conseguindo consumir!

Comment: Como você possui vários itens, tente construir um loop para pegar um por um. Para pegar a imagem, no seu caso muda um pouco por causa do array que sua API retorna, então ficaria algo como response.data.images[0].imageUrl.